# Why Row Locks Exist on An Completely Empty Partition in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning, dbcc, locks

I made a partitioned table with range left func. I then **insert some rows into just one partition**. Result:

```
select partition_id, partition_number, rows from sys.partitions where object_id = object_id('ptest')
```

result:

```
partition_id      partition_number rows
72057594464436224 1            8000
72057594464501760 2            0
72057594464567296 3            0
72057594464632832 4            0
```

then I update some rows of this table and query sys.dm_tran_locks, then **I find some RID Locks on partition4** like this:

```
select * from sys.dm_tran_locks where resource_type = 'RID'
```

Result like this:

```
Resource_type Resource_description    
RID 3:13:192
RID 1:153496:257
```

When I use **dbcc page** to verify what page 3:13 contains, I get nothing:

```
dbcc traceon(3604)
dbcc page(db, 3, 13, 3)
```

Result like this:

```
PAGE: (3:13)


BUFFER:


BUF @0x03E98BCC

bpage = 0x5A622000                   bhash = 0x00000000                   bpageno = (3:13)
bdbid = 11                           breferences = 0                      bUse1 = 38298
bstat = 0x1c0010b                    blog = 0x79797979                    bnext = 0x00000000

PAGE HEADER:


Page @0x5A622000

m_pageId = (3:13)                    m_headerVersion = 1                  m_type = 1
m_typeFlagBits = 0x4                 m_level = 0                          m_flagBits = 0xa008
m_objId (AllocUnitId.idObj) = 6973   m_indexId (AllocUnitId.idInd) = 256  
Metadata: AllocUnitId = 72057594494910464                                 
Metadata: PartitionId = 72057594464501760                                 Metadata: IndexId = 0
Metadata: ObjectId = 1967398128      m_prevPage = (0:0)                   m_nextPage = (0:0)
pminlen = 12                         m_slotCnt = 1                        m_freeCnt = 8094
m_freeData = 5867                    m_reservedCnt = 0                    m_lsn = (25294:376:199)
m_xactReserved = 0                   m_xdesId = (0:0)                     m_ghostRecCnt = 0
m_tornBits = -252731581              

Allocation Status

GAM (3:2) = ALLOCATED                SGAM (3:3) = ALLOCATED               
PFS (3:1) = 0x60 MIXED_EXT ALLOCATED   0_PCT_FULL                         DIFF (3:6) = CHANGED
ML (3:7) = NOT MIN_LOGGED
```

So, dbcc page confirms that there is nothing in page 3:13.
There comes my question, **why are RID locks exists on File 3:13 while nothing exists there**?

Comment: Or， question can also be like this: **Why SQL Server allocate pages on a completely empty partition？**

Comment: Can you post your partition function too?

Comment: @JNK: `CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION PFUNC (INT)
  AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES ( 1, 10000, 20000);
GO`

Comment: A nomal Field. It's a heap table has two columns. `CREATE TABLE TEST(ID INT, _SEQNO INT IDENTITY(1, 1) ON PSCHEMA(ID)`

Answer (score 0):

what's your " I update some rows of this table" T-SQL?
Maybe your update T-SQL made it be locked .
There isn't "nothing" here , there are still pages in the empty partition but no data

Comment: I use this `Update table set ID = ID + 1`. I wantna know why there are empty pages in empty partition?

Comment: **I have 4 partitions** and **DBCC IND** shows there is only pages in partition 1 which have actual data rows and in partition 4 which is the last partion and have 0 rows in it.